# MVVM Localization - Localized resources in View vs. in ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, localization

Is localization a responsibility of the View or of the ViewModel? Initially, I thought that it clearly belongs into the VM, as it is just data that needs to be displayed by the view. What exactly needs to be displayed is not important to the view. In addition, I have made the experience that XAML is more brittle than ViewModel code. But in a discussion today, some people strongly believed that localization is the responsibility of the view.

Here's some of the advantages I see for both versions:

Advantages of putting them into the View:

- ViewModel is oblivious of localization
- You can see the resource key in the XAML
- Less code

Advantages of putting them into the ViewModel:

- View is oblivious of localization
- The View does not need to know anything except for it's ViewModel
- It's easier to combine and create more complex strings.

In a Wpf application that uses the MVVM pattern, should the localizable elements (string resources) go into the view, or into the viewmodel? Why? What other advantages and disadvantages are there for the two approaches?

Some background info after comments: Assume that the Localization-backend is based on resx (not LocBaml). In addition, assume there was a framework that (View-Variant) could either transparently replace resource-ids in the view with the string, or that (ViewModel-Variant) would automatically generated INotifyPropertyChanged events for localized properties on the ViewModel.

However, I am mainly interested in arguments why it's better from a conceptual or cleaner-code point of view, disregarding the backend.

Comment: This could be considered primarily opinion based. I prefer a ViewModel-First approach in all cases. I leave strings as regular `resx` based resources in my apps and use a couple of helper classes to load them in the VM, then pass that to the View.

Comment: It does have an opinion component, sure, but there are (I hope) many more good reasons for or against each variant. I am interested in those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some resources belong to the View, and some resources belong to the ViewModel. I do not think there is a strict rule in that matter. Use your own judgment. Personally, I'm sharing the ViewModel's resource file with the View.

Answer (score 1):

To correctly implement localization in your WPF Application as it was designed, you need to follow the set procedure, so there is not really a choice like you are suggesting. For one thing. you'll need to set the `Uid` property on all of your UI controls, so that clearly can't be done in a view model. Furthermore, it is common to put all localized `string` values into separate dlls, so again, you can't do that in a view model.

I don't have the time to describe exactly how to do it right now. Instead, for full details about localization in WPF, please see the [WPF Globalization and Localization Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Why not? You can put all the strings as properties on the viewmodel, and the VM would query the backend for the correct string (from somewhere in a resx in a satellite dll).

Comment: Did you even look at the linked page? All I'm saying is that if you want to take advantage of the localization functionality that is *already* built in to WPF, then you'll have to follow their rules. However, if you'd prefer to re-invent the wheel, then of course you can do it anyway that you like... you'll end up with lots of extra and unnecessary code, but that's up to you.

Comment: I did read it, but it's not applicable for this: First, we need to use .resx in the backend (as Wpf is not the only Gui, and Mono doesn't support Wpf), and secondly, LocBaml and consorts offer a much less sophisticated environments (CSV) with less support by common translation tools.